# How to configure cpanel to notify you by email

Tags: configuration, cpanel

How can I configure cpanel in order to notify me by email each time after a new account is created for a new domain? Can I change the log it sends to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Server Configuration and on "Basic cPanel & WHM Setup" tab, you have to enter contact information (email address) for any case that may happen in the future.